# How to track number of AWS Lambda error retry

Tags: aws-lambda

In case of error or exception, Java AWS Lambda tries to re-invoke the function up to three times. Is there a way to keep track of the current invocation count, i.e. to know whether it is the first, second or third invocation?
Thanks

Comment: It would be great if AWS added this to the `context` object being passed in to the Lambda function

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding there are no built in Metrics in CloudWatch that tracks this.  One idea would be to log a timestamp with the parameters of the Lambda and then create a custom metric that checks for the same parameters being executed within a certain time interval.

That would not guarantee 100% accuracy, but it might provide a semi-accurate count of retries.

Comment: This would apply for lambda's invoked via the SDK or API Gateway.  For other event sources (SNS, Cloudwatch Logs, etc.) you should be able to pull the timestamp somewhere from the message that service sends to lambda.

Comment: I mean is there such a way to know which retrial I'm working on right now.  Can the context interface have this kind of information? Thanks